# The type 'System.Data.Linq.Binary' is not supported in aggregation operations - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
 (from chapter in Chapters
        join userChapter in UserChapters on chapter.Id equals userChapter.ChapterId
        join pub in Publications on chapter.Id equals pub.ChapterId into P 
        from publication in P.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where userChapter.UserId == 9
        group new
                           {
                               PubID = publication.Id,
                               Logo = chapter.Logo
                           } by new { chapter.Id, chapter.Name} into x
                           orderby x.Key.Name
        select new 
       {
           Id = x.Key.Id,
           chapterName = x.Key.Name,
           PublicationCount = x.Count(z => z.PubID > 0),
           Logo = x.Max(z=>z.Logo)
       }
)
```

In the above query "`chapter.Logo`" is of type `byte[]`, when I try to execute this query i am getting following error.

> The type 'System.Data.Linq.Binary' is not supported in aggregation operations - LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

```
    (from chapter in Chapters
    join userChapter in UserChapters on chapter.Id equals    userChapter.ChapterId
    join pub in Publications on chapter.Id equals pub.ChapterId into P 
    from publication in P.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where userChapter.UserId == 9
    group new
                       {
                           PubID = publication.Id,
                           Logo = chapter.Logo
                       } by new { chapter.Id, chapter.Name} into x
                       orderby x.Key.Name
    select new 
   {
       Id = x.Key.Id,
       chapterName = x.Key.Name,
       Logo = x.Max(z=>z.Logo.Count())
   }
```

)

Comment: When I execute the above query getting following error    'System.Data.Linq.Binary' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.Binary' could be found

Comment: can you tell me what does this query. means what you expect from this query ?

Comment: A user have list of chapters, a chapter have list of publications. I need the list of chapters along with the publication count.  The result should be as follows [
{
ID,
ChapterName,
PublicationCount, 
Logo
},
{
ID,
ChapterName, 
PublicationCount,
Logo
}

]

Answer (score 0):

```
    (from chapter in Chapters
    join userChapter in UserChapters on chapter.Id equals    userChapter.ChapterId
    join pub in Publications on chapter.Id equals pub.ChapterId into P 
    from pub in P.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where userChapter.UserId == 9
    group pub by new { chapter.Id, chapter.Name,chapter.Logo,pub.Id} into x
                       orderby x.Key.Name
    select new 
   {
       Id = x.Key.Id,
       chapterName = x.Key.Name,
       Logo = x.Key.Logo,
   PublicationCount=x.Count()
   }
```

)

Comment: Getting following error   "SQL Server does not handle comparison of NText, Text, Xml, or Image data types"

Comment: Following code works for me but I do not like subquery to get the chapter logo    Logo = (from chapter in KM_Chapters where chapter.Id == x.Key.Id select chapter.Logo)